# Find index of value in Vector, nearest to the input

Tags: c++, search, vector, c++11, std

Is there an efficient method of finding the index of a value in a Vector, closest to a reference value?

Comment: How efficient? There's `std::find`. I'm not sure if you mean something like `std::upper/lower_bound` with your last few words, though.

Comment: In a vector of random unsorted data it's going to be O(n). You can write your own loop or use one of standard algorithms.

Comment: I can't decide what you mean by efficient. jrok is right, classically the efficiency of any algorithm on unsorted data will not beat O(n), but sometimes people use efficienct to mean something quite different, like 'using as little code as possible', or 'won't embarrass me when I submit my homework'. So I would define your meaning more precisely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Computationally, if the vector is not sorted, you can't expect anything less than O(n), which may or may not meet your expectation. If it doesn't, you should change the data structure. If it does, you could use `std::min_element`, this way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int refElem = 42;
    std::vector<int> v{1, 5, 36, 50};
    auto i = min_element(begin(v), end(v), [=] (int x, int y)
    {
        return abs(x - refElem) < abs(y - refElem);
    });

    std::cout << std::distance(begin(v), i); // Prints 2
}
```

If the vector is sorted, on the other hand, you can use `std::lower_bound()` and `std::upper_bound()`, which have logarithmic complexity.

If you think complexity is an issue because of performance, **do some measurements before deciding to change the data structure**. Since vectors store their elements in a contiguous region of memory, a linear search resulting in high cache hit rate will often outperform a computationally more efficient algorithm on a data structure which allocates its element here and there in memory, resulting in frequent cache misses.

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks like linear search is your choice (at least for unsorted vector. It looks there is no point in sorting vector just for search.
2. In general everything depends on what do you mean under 'closest'. This 'closest' should be probably implemented as unary predicate. Predicate should return value like 0 if elements are equal and some value that is the bigger the less close element is from reference.
3. As I can see from <algorithm> most close algorithm to what you need is [std::min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) but you need not only range parameters but also reference element (or predicate which determines 'how close' is your element to reference.
4. Probably you can receive some benefit from checking if elements are equal and if so, breaking the loop.